# Adding my erc20 token to uniswap V3

Tags: erc-20, uniswap, uniswapv3

I want to add my custom token to Uniswap V3. What is confusing me is setting the range for my coin such as maximum and minimum limit. I was able to figure out what these limits mean. But as the sole provider of the token initially do I not need to provide the token from 0 to infinity?

Answer (score 0):

The price range that you choose is a personal decision based on the risk you are looking to take.

From a technical standpoint to save troubles with the pool. It is best to create a full position range first, this doesn't have to hold the majority of your LQ, but this will stop the pool from trading out of a Active/Initiated tick range, which causes issues with the pools pricing, and supply of liquidity.

Once you have a small position full range, you are free to add the majority of your Liquidity in a range that you expect it to be traded in, keeping in mind that the more liquidity the less impact your users experience, so make sure its a good range.

You are even able to add a single sided LQ position. If the range chosen is above or below the current price range, then you will only be able to add one of the two tokens. So sometimes when creating a token and not having the LQ for full backing at price, you are able to supply the LQ you have and put the remaining token into a single sided position.